# Gamma Function derivation using differentiation of definite integral?

Tags: integration, gamma-function

The usual derivation involves integration by parts technique, while I want a derivation using differentiation of definite integral. Is there a way? $$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt\,= (x-1)!$$
Wikipedia has the usual derivation using integration by parts, but can't this be done using differentiation of definite integral?

Comment: @Rohan come on man. I have seen this already. This is not what I am asking. What I want is a derivation directly starting from the expression $$\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt\,$$ and not starting from arbitrary function $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax}dt$$

Comment: You could try to differentiate the parameter $x$. However the tools involved with integral with parameters are not so easy to use, let alone those involved with improper integrals, since you have to check so many things, which is tedious in more general cases. P.S. we usually do not write $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$, since this only holds for integers which are commonly denoted by $n$.

Comment: I tried but I am getting an additional term of log(x-1)

Comment: I am convinced that you cannot prove that property by differentiating with respect to $x$. That kind of reasoning would work if Gamma satisfied a differential equation, but [as you can see here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/introductions/Gamma/ShowAll.html) there are no algebraic differential equations satisfied by Gamma.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but the definition of $\Gamma(x)$ involves $t^x$ whose derivative with respect to $x$ is not so easy to integrate or differentiate, so this computational method may not work for large numbers.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro yes I understand, when I differentiated $$ I(x) =  \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt\, $$ with respect to 'x' I got $$ \frac{d}{dx} I(x) = ln(x-1) I(x)\ $$ Does this have no solution? Is this a 'functional equation'? Sorry I don't know about these things as of now.

Comment: No need to be sorry, everybody is learning. That is a differential equation, a special case of functional equation (and a much more common case). It makes sense only for $x>1$, and on that interval, its general solution is $I(x)=C\Gamma(x)$ for $C\in\mathbb R$. IMHO, all of this is not useful towards the proof of $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-tr}dt\,= \frac 1r$$

Now differentiate $n-1$ times with respect to $r$ (within the integral sign on the left) to obtain:$$(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-rt}dt\,= (-1)^{n-1} \frac {(n-1)!}{r^n}$$ and evaluate at $r=1$.

Comment: I have seen this already. This is not what I am asking. What I want is a derivation directly starting from the expression $$\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-rt}dt\,$$ and not starting from arbitrary function $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-rt}dt$$ Is there a way?

Comment: @Vivek: come on, this answer is exactly what you are looking for. Does starting with "first note that ..." annoy you? Then just move it to the end of the post, so the computation starts with the differentiating of $\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-rt}\, dt$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro If I start from $$ \int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-rt}\, dt $$ how many times should I have to differentiate it with respect to 'r'? Can you show me the step by step process? I am not a PhD like you. I am still in school.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Don't use the fact that $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-rt}dt\,= \frac 1r $$ in doing so you are using integration by parts in a trivial manner.

Comment: @Vivek The whole point is to start with a simple expression on the right-hand side which you can differentiate easily lots of times. If you start with an integral involving $t^{n-1}$ the elementary way to reduce the power of $t$ is to use integration by parts. Differentiation increases the power. If you want to use differentiation, therefore, you have to start with a low power of $t$ like $t^0=1$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Got it... Excellent... Thanks